# Docker Container Existing after run with no error in log

Tags: python, azure, docker, docker-container, azure-dsvm

I have a python app consisting of image analysis models and 2 script files. In Main.py I have XMLRPC server to run forever listening to the clients.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    server = SimpleXMLRPCServer(("0.0.0.0", 8888))
    print("Listening on port 8888...")
    server.register_function(result, "result")
    server.serve_forever()
```

My Dcokerfile is:

```
# Start with NVIDIA's CUDA and cuDNN base image.
FROM nvidia/cuda:8.0-cudnn5-devel-ubuntu16.04

# Argument: the username & password.
ARG username
ARG user_password

# Update the system.
RUN echo "debconf debconf/frontend select Noninteractive" | debconf-set-selections
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade --assume-yes

...... bla bla bla

WORKDIR /home/${username}

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /home/${username}
ADD . /home/${username}

...... bla bla bla

# Expose the ports and start the ssh daemon as entry point.
USER root
EXPOSE 22 6006 8888
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

When I add CMD to run my Main.py The container does not work, It exiting immediately.
What is the best practice which I be able to Run this container? I am using azure Data Science Virtual Machine for Linux Ubuntu.

I built my Dockerfile with:

```
 docker build . --tag img_processing:V1 --build-arg "username=blabla" --build-arg "user_password=blabla"
```

And I Run my Container with:

```
docker run -d -p 4000:8888 img_processing
```

Currently I use `docker exec -it my-app-container bash` and inside of my container I manage stuff and Run `python Main.py &` to run the script in background which I don't think is a good way.
especially I have to find the way to scale up and process 3000 images at time. So each container needs to have same setup.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all never expose PORT 22 and run SSH inside containers. It is not a recommended thing to do

Next you can specify the either ENTRYPOINT or CMD as

```
CMD ["python", "Main.py"]
```

For this you need to make sure that `Main.py` is in the current directory of the `WORKDIR` that you have specified

You would only use `ENTRYPOINT` when you want that argument passed to your container run command are appended to the `ENTRYPOINT` command. In your case `CMD` should do.

When your contain exits immediately you should remove the `-d` flag and use `-it` flag to debug the issue

```
docker run -it -p 4000:8888 img_processing
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `ENTRYPOINT ["python", "Main.py"]`. This will set `python Main.py` to be the default command of the container. You can read more abou `ENTRYPOINT` in the Dockerfile [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint).